# first-child without certain class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select the first element under id #pid which contains the .pe class but not the .break class. Then obviously get a certain attribute from that element. I have tried different variations the following doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#pid .pe:not(.break):first-child").attr("data-time");
```

neither does :

```
$("#pid .pe:first-child").not(".break").attr("data-time");
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the select of the first child.

This should look like this:

```
alert($("#pid .pe:not(.break)").first().attr("data-time"));
```

Or as per Jay's suggestion -

```
$('#pid .pe:not(.break):first').attr('data-time');
```

[Fiddle example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d99y3gds/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#pid .pe:not(.break):first').attr('data-time');
```